# in C why the program is not reconizing the second if statement or upper case char variable?

Tags: c

Write a program that asks the user for an angle (in degrees).  Then, ask the user to type a letter.  If the user types a lower case letter, display the sine of the angle to four decimal places.   If the user types an upper case letter, display the cosine of the angle to four decimal places.

So this is what i have so far, why will the program not recognize the upper case and print the cosine?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

#define PI 3.14159265

main()
{
    int a;
    double x,y;
    char b;

    printf("What is the angle in degrees?\n");
    scanf("%i",&a);
    printf("Type a letter!\n");
    scanf("%i",&b);
    x=sin(a*PI/180);
    y=cos(a*PI/180);

    if (b>=97 | b<=122)
    {
        printf("The sine of %i is %.4f.\n",a,x);
    }
    if (b>=65 && b<=90) 
    {
        printf("The cosine of %i is %.4f.\n",a,y);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `|` and `&&` (and `||`) are very different, don´t use magic numbers, and make your question clearer.

Comment: What benefit do 97, 122, 65, and 90 have over 'a', 'z', 'A', and 'Z', respectively?

Comment: you can compare with characters instead of looking up the ASCII and using that. e.g: if(b>='a' && b<='z') and if(b>='A' && b<='Z')

Comment: @Randy, Also, it is a good idea to be clear about what happens compared to what you expect (error message vs nothing).

Comment: When will `if (b>=97 | b<=122)` be false?

Comment: no errors program runs and executes but will only print the sine. with upper or lower case input. still don't work samgak

Comment: `scanf("%i",&b);` -- This is wrong. `%i` reads an integer value and stores it in an object of type `int`. You're trying to store the result in `b`, which is of type `char`. Try `scanf(" %c", &b);` (the space makes it skip leading whitespace, including the newline you typed after entering the angle).

Comment: Turn warnings on in your compiler, and fix those first.

Answer (score 2):

Because `if(b>= 97 | b <= 122)` will always be true.

It should be `if(b>=97 && b<=122)` instead, which limits `b` in the range of lowercase.

Personally I prefer to write as `if (97 <= b && b <= 122)` which makes it easy to see its range.

Comment: Better would be to use `islower()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Do you think this would be easier if you use the library `<ctype.h>`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.14159265

int main()

{
    int a;
    double x,y;
    char b;

    printf("What is the angle in degrees?\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Type a letter!\n");
    scanf(" %c", &b);

    x=sin(a*PI/180);
    y=cos(a*PI/180);

    if (isupper(b))
    {
        printf("The sine of %d is %.4f.\n",a,x);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The cosine of %d is %.4f.\n",a,y);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe also use `isalpha(b)` first, or at least `isupper(b)` on the `else`, to make sure a letter was actually entered and not something else.

Comment: `isalpha(b)` has undefined behavior if `b` happens to be negative (not likely, but possible if you enter an accented letter, for example). You need to use `isalpha((unsigned char)b)`. Yes, it's annoying and counterintuitive.